# Using the user's username as path for opening a file

Tags: c#, path

I recently had to make a button in C# that simply had to open a text file. The job was easy until I realized that I had no ideea how to open the file, why? Well simply because I can't think of a way to "define" the user's name in the path to the file.

Here is the code I tryed to use:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\SchoolProject\\file.txt");
    }
    catch { }
}
```

And, it did not work.

So what's the solution to this problem? If you feel like knowing the answer please be very explicit about it, I'm new to programming languages and I don't quite understand the codes so well.
( If you can and if it's not too much to ask please include the code that should work in your answer.)

Comment: Have you tried `echo %userprofile%`? It should be obvious why your code doesn't work if you do.

Comment: And removing that empty catch block would also give you some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand environment variable use: [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Replaces the name of each environment variable embedded in the
>   specified string with the string equivalent of the value of the
>   variable, then returns the resulting string.

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\SchoolProject\\file.txt");
```

This will give you the exact path.

So your code could be:

```
string filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\SchoolProject\\file.txt");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

Also, having an empty `try-catch` will not help you in determining the exception, catch specific exception or at least base class `Exception` and then you can log/look in the debugger, at the exception and its message.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. +1 for teaching me something I didn't know you could do.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to all of these "special" folder locations via the `Environment.SpecialFolders` enum and the `GetFolderPath` method.

In your case, you want `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`. Something like:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test.txt");
```

All the special folders can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).